# Docker run php script

Tags: php, docker

I have some script for irc bot and want to run it with `docker run -d  --name php-fpm php:5 irc_bot.php` however it doesn't work.
I don't need web server : apach, nginx, but only clli is needed.

Do you know how to simply run `php irc_bot.php` with online docker command?

Comment: Wrt the only needing php cli, there are cli only versions available, check out the [hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/).

Comment: You mean `docker run -d  --name php-fpm php:5.6-cli irc_bot.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you're missing appears to be a volume. The container doesn't actually have a "irc_bot.php", so you probably need something like...

```
docker run -d -v /directory/with/file/:/dir/to/run/from/ php:5.6-cli php /dir/to/run/from/irc_bot.php
```

The -v mounts the first path as a volume on the container so you have access to all the files inside the container, then the end part is simply the command you want to run.